# Calculate the average of the rolling last 4 weeks

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need your help.

Database: SQL SERVER 2008R2

I want to calculate for a year and a week the average of value of the 4 last weeks.

I have data a table like that:

```
YEAR    WEEKS   VALUE 
2012    1   3000
2012    2   5000
2012    3   6000
2012    4   7000
2012    5   8000
2012    6   9000
2012    7   1000
2012    8   6000
2012    9   9000
2012    10  4000
```

And I want that:

```
YEAR       WEEKS      VALUE
2012        1           ( Average value for week 49, 50, 51, 52 for the year 2011)
2012        2         ( Average value for week 50, 51, 52 for the year 2011 and week 1                    for the year 2012)
2012        3           ( Average value for week 51, 52 for the year 2011 and week 1, 2 for the year 2012)
2012        4           ( Average value for week 52 for the year 2011 and week 1, 2, 3 for the year 2012)
2012        5          5250 -> (  Average value for  week 1, 2, 3 , 4 for the year 2012)
2012        6          6500 -> (  Average value for  week 2, 3 , 4, 5 for the year 2012)
```

Comment: no attempt/effort shown.

Comment: Ooops !! It's more comprehensive like that

Comment: How many weeks in each year? Is it variable?

Comment: You can get your question reopened if you improve it. Show us what you've tried. Answer my question about # of weeks in a year. Provide some DDL that creates a sample data set.

Comment: I had a similar question and the answer is a good one.

Answer (score 3):

If years always have 52 weeks then here's an easy way:

```
SELECT
   DataYear = N.Serial / 52,
   DataWeek = N.Serial % 52 + 1,
   Avg(T.Value)
FROM
   dbo.DataTable T
   CROSS JOIN (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3)) W (Offset)
   CROSS APPLY (SELECT T.Year * 52 + Week + W.Offset) N (Serial)
GROUP BY
   N.Serial / 52,
   N.Serial % 52 + 1
HAVING
   Count(*) = 4 -- if you don't want smaller sets
ORDER BY
   DataYear,
   DataWeek;
```

[See this in action in a SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a35df/4). I had to add fake data for the end of 2011 to match your sample output. I borrowed the 2011 data from Alexander Fedorenko to make comparison easy.

Note: if years have a variable number of weeks it will not be so simple. To get a better answer, you need to provide very specific instructions on how weeks are calculated, enough detail so that we can determine the actual starting date of each week in a year.

Ultimately, storing data split apart into years and weeks may not be optimal. I think it is probably better to simply store the week starting date for each week of data that is collected.

Comment: +1 very interesting and fast solution, especially for CROSS JOIN + CROSS APPLY.Thanks for magnificent lessons ErikE;)

Comment: Thank you! CROSS APPLY is great when you want to use an expression more than once.

Answer (score 1):

use recursive [**CTE**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT [YEAR], WEEKS, VALUE,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [YEAR], WEEKS) AS id
  FROM your_table
  --WHERE your condition range of dates
  ), cte2 AS
 (
  SELECT id,
         CASE WHEN id = 5 THEN [YEAR] END AS [YEAR],
         CASE WHEN id = 5 THEN WEEKS END AS WEEKS,
         CASE WHEN id != 5 THEN VALUE END AS VALUE, 1 AS [Level]
  FROM cte
  UNION ALL
  SELECT c.id,
         CASE WHEN ct.id - ct.[Level] = 4 THEN c.[YEAR] END,
         CASE WHEN ct.id - ct.[Level] = 4 THEN c.WEEKS END,
         CASE WHEN ct.id - ct.[Level] != 4 THEN c.VALUE END, ct.[Level] + 1
  FROM cte c JOIN cte2 ct ON c.id = ct.id + 1
  WHERE ct.id < 5 + [Level]
  )
  SELECT MAX([YEAR]) AS [YEAR], MAX(WEEKS) AS WEEKS, AVG(VALUE) AS avgVALUE
  FROM cte2
  WHERE id = CASE WHEN [Level] = 1 AND id > 5 THEN NULL ELSE id END 
  GROUP BY [level]
  HAVING MAX([YEAR]) IS NOT NULL
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d6db6/2)

Comment: Seriously, hard-coding years????

Comment: This works correctly. See a simpler solution in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't split date information across multiple fields it means they have to be recombined slowing your query down, better to store it as a datetime variable.

Second, an answer is

```
WITH  Data
AS
(
    SELECT   CAST(CAST(Year AS VARCHAR) + CAST(Weeks AS VARCHAR) AS INTEGER) AS WeekNum
            ,Year
            ,Weeks
            ,Value
            ,1 AS Depth
    FROM    WeekData
    UNION ALL
    SELECT   d.WeekNum
            ,d.Year
            ,d.Weeks
            ,wd.Value
            ,d.Depth + 1
    FROM    WeekData wd
            INNER JOIN
            Data d  ON d.WeekNum=CAST(CAST(wd.Year AS VARCHAR) + CAST(wd.Weeks AS VARCHAR) AS INTEGER)-d.Depth
                    AND
                    d.Depth<4
)
SELECT   Year
        ,Weeks
        ,AVG(Value) AS AverageValue
FROM    Data
GROUP BY Year
        ,Weeks
```

Comment: [Your query (SQLFiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a1413/4) is not giving the right answer. The first row should be `2012`, `1`.